# WPF Window doesn't refresh when running over RDP

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a rather odd problem. I am using INotifyPropertyChanged to control the Visibility behavior of my application. When certain criteria are met, the window displays with updated information. In order to meet design guidelines I have disabled the chrome and added my own close, move and hide logic. Everything works great except for one very annoying behavior. When I am running the program in RDP mode, if I hide the window by changing it's visibility to collapsed, then minimize the RDP session and restore it. My window no longer refreshes to show the latest information. I have tried everything including invalidate visual, update layout, using a render delegate. Nothing works. The application is running and I can see that the actual data is changing during debugging but the RDP session is refusing to redraw it. Even stranger is that I can drag the window around and the RDP session is redrawing it within the desktop but nothing within the window changes. It's like it's frozen in time.

Here is the xaml for my window:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
    xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="{Binding WinHeight}" 
    Width="{Binding WinWidth}"
    Top="{Binding WinTop}"
    Left="{Binding WinLeft}"
    ShowInTaskbar="False" 
    WindowStyle="None" 
    BorderThickness="0" 
    Background="Transparent" 
    AllowsTransparency="True" 
    Visibility="{Binding DisplayWindow}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution ended up being that I needed to set AllowTransparency="False". For some reason, transparency in RDP can cause refresh issues. I had to sacrifice the fancier rounded corners but now the window refreshes as needed.

P.S. After removing transparency it's possible that you will be left with a window that shows a 4 pixel gray border. In order to remove that border just set ResizeMode="NoResize".

Comment: I am glad that solved your problem.  Have you experienced any of the other artifacts that I described in my answer?  One of the most visible is the gradient stepping problem.  Personally I dont recommend writing programs with WPF interfaces if they are going to be hosted over a RDP, Citrix, or VM AND you want them to look good.  If you are going for plain Jane, no problem, but I have not had a customized UI yet that performed the way I wanted it to running through one of those platforms.

Comment: Actually, I have not experienced any of the issues which you mentioned but that is because in this particular app, we're not using any gradient graphics or 3d. We are using the datagrid from the wpf toolkit and I have logic which expands all rows and collapses them, this particular part takes a few seconds to redraw on slower machines but it's tolerable. I found this other article which deals with deployement over rdp: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/02/27/optimizing-visual-studio-2010-and-wpf-applications-for-remote-desktop.aspx

Comment: The property name is "AllowsTransparency" and not "AllowTransparency" as written.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this before in some apps that I have written with very simple UI.  Buttons are not drawn correctly, borders are missing, lists don't refresh, gradients  experience a color stepping artifact where they dont gradually change from one color to another, etc.

I have always thought this was a problem with the fact that WPF uses the graphic hardware to render, and RDP and VM boxes do some funny shenanigans with graphics.  I am not sure what RemoteDesktop does as far as its rendered output, but VM boxes usually use a mocked up generic graphic controller which does not always produce what you expect.

On the following article I found this :

> On the server, RDP uses its own video driver to render display output
>   by constructing the rendering information into network packets by
>   using RDP protocol and sending them over the network to the client.

[Remote Desktop Protocol - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383015%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Which makes it sound like a graphics driver is used to render the output rather than the graphic chipset (which I guess makes sense).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately that link did not provide me with a solution. I will post the answer below for anyone else experiencing this issue.